# In SSMS, anyway to save a variable in memory and use without highlighting?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is it possible to create a variable in SSMS and then be able to use it without highlighting it?

For example, I can run the following two statements together and it works fine:

```
DECLARE @myVariable varchar = 'Test'
SELECT @myVariable
```

But I can't run

```
DECLARE @myVariable varchar = 'Test'
```

and then run

```
SELECT @myVariable
```

separately without having to have the DECLARE highlighted as part of the same statement.

I guess I'm asking is there a way to put my variables in global memory in SSMS so I can run queries without having to constantly run the DECLARE command?  Thanks

(I'm working on a presentation demo and it is annoying to have to constantly highlight the DECLARE statements!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No because this isn't an SSMS thing, it's a SQL thing. The DECLARE is only in scope as part of the batch, if you submit another batch without the variable then it won't be declared and thus the error you get.

It doesn't matter what interface you use, you need to have the variable defined per batch.